# Is it possible to connect multiple WS2812 LED Strips to a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: gpio, power, led

im new to the Raspberry Pi in general and followed this tutorial https://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/ws2812 to control a single LED Strip.

I was wondering if it was possible two control a second strip with a different GPIO Pin and additional Power Supply for the strip.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: yes. it is possible...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, up to 16 strings of WS2812 LEDs, see [this blog post](https://iosoft.blog/raspberry-pi-multi-channel-ws2812/)

Some developers have driven thousands of LEDs this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yea. Raspberry pi has 2 PWM outputs going to 4 pins. See https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pwm# for pinout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).